# Is it OK to have all my javascript in application.js, and use require_tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to Rails, and this is more of a "best practice" question. Please let me know if I should be asking this on another SE site.

Up until now I've been taking the asset pipeline for granted. As the assets (CSS and JS) become more complex though, it started to occur to me that it's probably not very efficient to have all of them load for every single page. What I currently have is something like this:

**application.js:**

```
...
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {

    //page A scripts/handlers
    ...

    //page B scripts/handlers
    ...

    //page C scripts/handlers
    ...
});
```

My understanding is that this entire code will be loaded on Page A, Page B and Page C because of `require_tree`. Is that correct?

Should I start thinking about removing `require_tree` and segregating these assets into their own controller-specific asset files, with application.js and application.css containing only the "shared" scripts/handlers/styles, and then loading them with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

or

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

Or am I overthinking it? My main concern is that as my application gets more complex, I'm going to need to manage complexity efficiently. So I'd rather start doing things the right way now, as opposed to dealing with the headache later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really a matter of preference. There's no right and wrong (depending on who you ask) so really, how do you want your app to work?

You're absolutely right, that using the `require_tree` in application.js will combine all of your js files into a single asset, and it will be loaded onto every page, BUT when rails is put into production mode, and your assets are precompiled, 2 things will happen

- The code will be minified
- Your assets will be 'fingerprinted' for caching purposes

What will then happen, is your 'big' javascript file will become a LOT smaller. The other thing that will happen, is rails will move this compressed file into the `public` folder, making it a static asset. Once this happens, the web server that rails is running on can let your browser know that it can cache it, so even though every page in your app will reference it, your browser will only download it once (until the fingerprint changes or you clear your cache)

As an idea of how effective this can be, an app I've been working on recently has a pretty damn big javascript structure, where the uncompressed `application.js` file was downloading at 2MB+. In development mode, this was downloaded every time the page was reloaded, so as you can imagine, this was very slow.

Once we put rails into production mode and compiled our assets, the js file became around 500KB, and was downloaded once. MUCH better!

This is also true of your CSS files and images, although obviously images won't become one big image file with everything in.

If you speak to some hardcore JS people, using the asset pipeline isn't the best option as handling dependencies in your JS can get a bit ugly, at which point you should look at using libraries such as RequireJS or Browserify. But given you're quite new to rails, I'd avoid this for now.

So, at the end of it all it's really your choice. If you'd like to have a javascript file for each page, then go for it! The asset pipeline will work as you expect, it'll still compile them into static files, and the browser will still cache them. One thing you will have to do however, is tell rails that you want to compile more than just one JS file.

By default, when in production, rails will only precompile the `application.js` file. If you choose to have multiple files, then this isn't what you want. You'll need to change this to tell rails that you want it to compile all of the JS files in your assets folder. You can do this in the `production.rb` file. A quick google or stack overflow search will show you how to do this, but it's really straight forward.

If you choose to stick with the require_tree option, then you don't need to do anything, and rails in production is already setup for you :)

Comment: Okay, I understand that this pertains to files being downloaded and cached (network utilization). But what about web page performance? When I use Chrome's audit tool on my pages, one of the first warnings that come up is "Remove unused CSS - 90% of application.css is not used on this page". My understanding is that unused rules can slow down page rendering.

Comment: In theory that's true yes, but it really depends on how big you stylesheet is. If you're looking at thousands of rules, then sure, split it up, but if not then you're probably looking at an un-noticeable slowdown. Good explanation of that here https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload?csw=1#RemoveUnusedCSS

Answer (score 0):

Usually I like to use content_for on the layout. (ex: application.html.erb)

```
<% if content_for?(:custom_css) %>
<%= yield(:custom_css) %>
<% end %>

<% if content_for?(:custom_js) %>
<%= yield(:custom_js) %>
<% end %>
```

and include the files on the custom view: (ex: index.html.erb)

```
<% content_for :custom_css do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "common/timepicker/jquery.timepicker", :media => 'all', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<% end %>
```

I don't like to put all scripts and styles on application.js because in some big applications (no single page applications) it gonna remove a lot of styles and scripts unused on the request. And for some kind of applications with roles and admin or default user areas, maybe some users don't need to load all the scripts and styles.